# Use the gpstime attribute of a point cloud

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a point cloud (LAZ format). I want to create **a python action** that allows me to query a gpstime variable to know the shooting date.

I started writing a script but I don't know how to access the "Gpstime" variable.
do you have an idea?

in my example Gpstime = n

```
import datetime
curr_date = "14-09-2011 00:00:00"
n = 341415420.0000000000
'n = (((n//60)//60)//24)'
curr_date_temp = datetime.datetime.strptime(curr_date,"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
new_date = curr_date_temp + datetime.timedelta(seconds=n)
print("la date de prise de vue est le : ", new_date)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a code snippet how to access statistics from a point cloud layer:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() #the PointCloud layer is the active Layer
print(layer.statistics().minimum('GpsTime')) #min Value of GPS Time
```

Comment: this works, but it seems that we cannot create python actions with point layers. I need to find a solution..

Comment: that is right, Actions for point cloud layers are not available until now, but you can make a feature request for that: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Comment: OK thanks, I will do it. On the other hand, I wonder if while waiting, it is not possible to create a button in Qgis to launch my script?

Comment: you have 2 possibilities: make a Plugin, which adds a button with your functionallity oder make a processing script, where you can control in- and output.

Comment: it 's done  : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/56656

Answer (score 0):

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() #selection du nuage de point
print(layer.statistics().minimum('GpsTime')) #statistique de la couche point
n= (layer.statistics().minimum('GpsTime'))
import datetime
curr_date = "14-09-2011 00:00:00"
curr_date_temp = datetime.datetime.strptime(curr_date,"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
new_date = curr_date_temp + datetime.timedelta(seconds=n)
print("la date de prise de vue est le : ", new_date)
```